# How to add animation onPressed and onReleased in QML Slider?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-sliderstyle.html

```
Slider {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    style: SliderStyle {
        groove: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 200
            implicitHeight: 8
            color: "gray"
            radius: 8
        }
        handle: Rectangle {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            color: control.pressed ? "white" : "lightgray"
            border.color: "gray"
            border.width: 2
            implicitWidth: 34
            implicitHeight: 34
            radius: 12
        }
    }
```

How to access the `onReleased` and `onPressed` of the slider in order to start and stop some animation?

Here is what I tried:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    Slider
    {
        id: head
        property Rectangle thumb: thumb
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        style: SliderStyle {
            groove: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 200
                implicitHeight: 8
                color: "gray"
                radius: 8
            }
            handle: Rectangle {
                id: thumb
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                color: control.pressed ? "white" : "lightgray"
                border.color: "gray"
                border.width: 2
                implicitWidth: 34
                implicitHeight: 34
                radius: 12
            }
        }

        onPressedChanged:
        {
            if(pressed)
            {
                console.log("pressed")
                returnAnimation.stop()
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("released")
                returnAnimation.start()
            }
        }

        ParallelAnimation {
            id: returnAnimation
            NumberAnimation { target: thumb.anchors; property: "horizontalCenterOffset";
                to: 0; duration: 200; easing.type: Easing.OutSine }
            NumberAnimation { target: thumb.anchors; property: "verticalCenterOffset";
                to: 0; duration: 200; easing.type: Easing.OutSine }
        }

    }
}
```

Error:

> ReferenceError: thumb is not defined

Comment: What about [Slider.pressed](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-slider.html#pressed-prop)?

Comment: Bumped on this question while reading other stuff. Did you solve your issues?

Comment: No, these answers didn't work for me. @BaCaRoZzo

Comment: I see. I can try to provide some guidelines but looking at your code I'm not sure about the result you want to achieve. Is it something like [the android effect to the bottom](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/sliders.html#sliders-discrete-slider)?

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo I want the effect exactly like this virtual joystick. https://github.com/aaronsnoswell/QMLVirtualJoystick Thanks for your time.

Comment: Cool effect. Sorry for the questions. Unfortunately there's something missing for me and I would like to understand these stuff. Do you want a slider whose value grows while the handle is dragged in the upper semicircle and decrease while dragged in the lower semicircle? Something different? Something in the middle? You can surely heavy tweak the `Slider` to be similar to this joystick component but I'm not sure it is worth the effort: you can provide a `value` property to the joystick and recalculate it according to the handle position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fully working example. You will have to create your own images referenced here since I can't attach them.

I have found scoping is tricky in QML with component objects. The ":style:handle" component in Slider can "see out" to the higher levels but the higher levels cannot "see in" to the ":style:handle" component.

General Strategy

1. Create a property in the Top Level Slider scope
2. Use the property inside the ":style:handle" component since it can "see out"
3. Use the higher level onPressedChanged handler and the pressed property to adjust the high level property which will be "seen" by the low level component.

---

```
Slider {
    id: portVoltageSlider

    width: 100; height: 27
    maximumValue: 150; minimumValue: -150
    value: 0.00
    stepSize: 10

    anchors { centerIn: parent }

    // style:handle component will be able to see/access this property
    // opacity value of style: SliderStyle:handle.sliderHover
    property real hoverOpacity: 0

    // adjust property on slider pressed
    onPressedChanged: {
        // show slider Hover when pressed, hide otherwise
        if( pressed ) {
            console.log("slider pressed. show hover.")
            hoverShowAnimation.start()
        }
        else {
            console.log("slider released. hide hover.")
            hoverHideAnimation.start()
        }
    }

   // gratuitous animation using opacity
   PropertyAnimation {
        id: hoverShowAnimation
        target: portVoltageSlider; properties: "hoverOpacity"; from: portVoltageSlider.hoverOpacity; to: 1; duration: 500
    }

    PropertyAnimation {
        id: hoverHideAnimation
        target: portVoltageSlider; properties: "hoverOpacity"; from: portVoltageSlider.hoverOpacity; to: 0; duration: 500
    }

   style: SliderStyle {
        id: sliderStyle

        property bool hoverVisible: false

        groove: Rectangle {
            //                        x: slider1.leftPadding
            y: portVoltageSlider.topPadding + portVoltageSlider.availableHeight / 2 - height / 2
            implicitWidth: 200; implicitHeight: 4
            width: portVoltageSlider.availableWidth; height: implicitHeight
            radius: 2
            color: "#bdbebf"

            Rectangle {
                width: portVoltageSlider.visualPosition * parent.width; height: parent.height
                color: "yellow"
                radius: 2
            }
        }

        handle: Image {
            id: sliderHandle

            width: 22; height: 24
            source: "sliderThumb.svg"
            anchors { centerIn: parent }

            Image {
                id: sliderHover

                width: 22; height: 24
                source: "sliderValue.svg"
                anchors { bottom: sliderHandle.top }
                opacity: portVoltageSlider.hoverOpacity

                Label {
                    id: check

                    anchors {centerIn: parent; verticalCenterOffset: -4 }
                    text: portVoltageSlider.value
                    font.pointSize: 6
                    font.bold: true
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

That what I meant in the comment above:

```
 Slider {
    ...
    onPressedChanged: {
        if(pressed)
            console.log("pressed")
        else
            console.log("released")
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I have edited the question according to your answer. Still not working *completely* as desired. Please point out where I am going wrong. am getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    Slider
    {
        id: head
        property Rectangle thumb: thumb

        //Added these signals:
        signal startAnim
        signal stopAnim

        anchors.centerIn: parent
        style: SliderStyle {
            groove: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 200
                implicitHeight: 8
                color: "gray"
                radius: 8
            }
            handle: Rectangle {
                id: thumb
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                color: control.pressed ? "white" : "lightgray"
                border.color: "gray"
                border.width: 2
                implicitWidth: 34
                implicitHeight: 34
                radius: 12

                //Moved animation within the confines of the object that it actually pertains to
                ParallelAnimation {
                    id: returnAnimation
                    NumberAnimation { target: thumb.anchors; property: "horizontalCenterOffset";
                        to: 0; duration: 200; easing.type: Easing.OutSine }
                    NumberAnimation { target: thumb.anchors; property: "verticalCenterOffset";
                        to: 0; duration: 200; easing.type: Easing.OutSine }
                }

                //Signal connections done here:
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    head.startAnim.connect(returnAnimation.start)
                    head.stopAnim.connect(returnAnimation.stop)
                }
            }
        }

        onPressedChanged:
        {
            if(pressed)
            {
                console.log("pressed")
                startAnim()
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("released")
                stopAnim()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this. No errors are shown but _no_ animation is also shown.